# Difference between convergent precipitation and cyclone precipitation?

Tags: meteorology, climate, precipitation

What exactly is the difference between convergent precipitation and cyclone precipitation, their generation and characteristics?

Comment: It does not seem to me that "convergent precipitation" is common vocabulary as there are only 400 google results. According to this book http://bit.ly/1ZJtVdw, convergent precipitation occurs, when air is lifted due to horizontal convergence of air. However I don't like that explanation cause I can't think of any possibility to achieve lifting of air without hor. convergence at some level.